# Insert or replace in SQLite

Tags: sql, ios, sqlite

I want to insert or replace in SQLite by 2 fields Varchar and Integer. These 2 fields should be unique. So i have to create special table with 2 fields as unique ?

Maybe some one could help on this.

Comment: is it the combination of the two fields that is unique, or each field on its own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the combination of two fields to be unique, the easiest way is to create a unique index on these fields:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX field1_field2_idx ON table_name(field1, field2)
```

then in case of a conflict the `INSERT OR REPLACE` statement will replace the existing record with the new one.